Blowup not smooth
I came across the following problem:
Let $k=F_p(t)$.  Take the closed subscheme $S=V(x^p-tz,y)$ of $\mathbb{P}^2=\text{Proj }k[x,y,z]$.  Show the blowup of $S$ is not smooth.
I suppose the first point of confusion is that $x^p-tz$ is not homogeneous.  Do I need to find homogeneous generators of $(x^p-tz,y)$?
Assuming that's resolved, should the strategy then be to find the defining ideal of the blowup and then look for singularities?
Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: the problem in question comes from the first exercise sheet at this site: https://math.rice.edu/~av15/dPsK3s.html
Edit: if the problem is simply bricked because of nonhomogeneity, then what happens if we replace $x^p-tz$ with something homogeneous, like say $x-tz$?

Welcome to MSE. One thing that would help your question would be if you would mention the source of this problem - it may be that your confusion is covered in an erratum to the original text, or the like. Please add this information with an [edit]. The issue you're identifying here is rather serious - the ideal as written is not homogeneous.

Hi, thank you for the comment.  I edited in the source above.
